# How do I ask the user to enter 10 positive numbers in array of integers and if its less than 0 its invalid

Tags: arrays

This is what i got so far. I also dont know how to display smallest and largest and even and odd inputs to display. Someone please help

int value = -1;

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(value < 0) 
    {
      System.out.print("Enter a value > 0: ");

      value = scanner.nextInt();

    }
      if(value < 0)

      System.out.println("sorry write a value > 0");

    }
```

Comment: What is `Scanner`? Is this Java? You should tag with the correct language.

Comment: Typo? `while(value > 0)` ?!

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number =value.nextInt();

    if (number < 0 ) {
        System.out.println("Value entered less than zero");
    }
    else if (number == 0) {
        System.out.println("Value entered is equal to zero");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Value must have been greater than zero.");
    }
}
```

}